# How to get out a childview from RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, activity-transition

[EDITED AT THE BOTTOM]

I'm trying to code manually these types of animations:

[Google Calendar](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-V0KHNRjbE_UmFGUTc1NnhJUDg/view?usp=sharing)

If you carefully see those views, they belong to a List or RecyclerView, but they are animated (size animation, translation animation) out of the **parent**'s bounds.

If I try to do that, the result is that my view goes under my parent's bounds.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-V0KHNRjbE_bkJEekExNGNLbDA/view?usp=sharing

---

This is one frame, carefully stopped just to see that the child view has been taken from the parent, and is starting expanding to the whole view:

[image]

and this is where it's almost 100% expanded:

[image]

---

I just wanted to re-point this in another way. Is this a stuff in relation with [Activity Transitions](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/material/animations.html) ? Because if so, I don't have any idea of how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways to achieve this effect:

One way is using Shared Element Activity Transition. It will require using 2 activities: one with recycler view, second with full screen view. Animation will be automatically applied between switching between activity one and activity two. This solution will work and does not require much code, but you will run into a problem of keeping two activities in sync (such as exact position of RecyclerView). Customization is not impossible, but could be difficult as you are heavily relying on the framework.

Second way, is staying within the same activity and using object animators to transition between your recycler view item and full screen view. The trick is not to animate the view that is located inside of RecyclerView, but animate your full screen view from the boundaries of the view that is located inside the RecyclerView. This way, you will not be limited by parent's boundaries. I went ahead and implemented second solution as it is highly customizable and gives you a full control over all the animations.

This sample app includes translation and scaling animators. It will animate from little square position view on the left side of the screen. This behavior can be easily changed.

Demo: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/87080012/device-2016-03-25-160611.mp4

Link to project repo: https://dkarmazi@bitbucket.org/dkarmazi/androidrecyclerviewanimation.git

Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Adapter.ItemClickListener, CustomView.CloseButtonClickListener {
    public static final int ANIMATION_SPEED = 3000;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private CustomView customView;
    private RelativeLayout rootView;
    private Rect lastClickedRecyclerViewItemRect;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rootView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_view);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        customView = (CustomView) findViewById(R.id.custom_view);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new Adapter(getApplicationContext(), this, getSampleData()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(View clickedView, int position, String title) {
        lastClickedRecyclerViewItemRect = new Rect();
        clickedView.getGlobalVisibleRect(lastClickedRecyclerViewItemRect);

        Rect targetViewRect = new Rect();
        rootView.getGlobalVisibleRect(targetViewRect);

        AnimatorSet animatorSet = getViewToViewScalingAnimator(rootView, customView, lastClickedRecyclerViewItemRect, targetViewRect, ANIMATION_SPEED, 0);

        customView.setData(position, title, this);
        customView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        animatorSet.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCloseButtonClicked(int position) {
        Rect clickedViewRect = new Rect();
        customView.getGlobalVisibleRect(clickedViewRect);
        AnimatorSet animatorSet = getViewToViewScalingAnimator(rootView, customView, clickedViewRect, lastClickedRecyclerViewItemRect, ANIMATION_SPEED, 0);

        animatorSet.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                // no op
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                customView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                // no op
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                // no op
            }
        });

        animatorSet.start();
    }

    public static AnimatorSet getViewToViewScalingAnimator(final RelativeLayout parentView,
                                                           final View viewToAnimate,
                                                           final Rect fromViewRect,
                                                           final Rect toViewRect,
                                                           final long duration,
                                                           final long startDelay) {
        // get all coordinates at once
        final Rect parentViewRect = new Rect(), viewToAnimateRect = new Rect();
        parentView.getGlobalVisibleRect(parentViewRect);
        viewToAnimate.getGlobalVisibleRect(viewToAnimateRect);

        viewToAnimate.setScaleX(1f);
        viewToAnimate.setScaleY(1f);

        // rescaling of the object on X-axis
        final ValueAnimator valueAnimatorWidth = ValueAnimator.ofInt(fromViewRect.width(), toViewRect.width());
        valueAnimatorWidth.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                // Get animated width value update
                int newWidth = (int) valueAnimatorWidth.getAnimatedValue();

                // Get and update LayoutParams of the animated view
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) viewToAnimate.getLayoutParams();

                lp.width = newWidth;
                viewToAnimate.setLayoutParams(lp);
            }
        });

        // rescaling of the object on Y-axis
        final ValueAnimator valueAnimatorHeight = ValueAnimator.ofInt(fromViewRect.height(), toViewRect.height());
        valueAnimatorHeight.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                // Get animated width value update
                int newHeight = (int) valueAnimatorHeight.getAnimatedValue();

                // Get and update LayoutParams of the animated view
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) viewToAnimate.getLayoutParams();
                lp.height = newHeight;
                viewToAnimate.setLayoutParams(lp);
            }
        });

        // moving of the object on X-axis
        ObjectAnimator translateAnimatorX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewToAnimate, "X", fromViewRect.left - parentViewRect.left, toViewRect.left - parentViewRect.left);

        // moving of the object on Y-axis
        ObjectAnimator translateAnimatorY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewToAnimate, "Y", fromViewRect.top - parentViewRect.top, toViewRect.top - parentViewRect.top);

        AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
        animatorSet.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(1f));
        animatorSet.setDuration(duration); // can be decoupled for each animator separately
        animatorSet.setStartDelay(startDelay); // can be decoupled for each animator separately
        animatorSet.playTogether(valueAnimatorWidth, valueAnimatorHeight, translateAnimatorX, translateAnimatorY);

        return animatorSet;
    }

    private static List<String> getSampleData() {
        List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
        dataList.add("zero");
        dataList.add("one");
        dataList.add("two");
        dataList.add("three");
        dataList.add("four");
        dataList.add("five");
        dataList.add("six");
        dataList.add("seven");
        dataList.add("eight");
        dataList.add("nine");
        dataList.add("ten");
        dataList.add("eleven");
        dataList.add("twelve");
        dataList.add("thirteen");
        dataList.add("fourteen");
        dataList.add("fifteen");
        dataList.add("sixteen");
        dataList.add("seventeen");
        dataList.add("eighteen");
        dataList.add("nineteen");
        dataList.add("twenty");

        return dataList;
    }
}
```

Activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>

    <com.dkarmazi.android.myapplication.CustomView
        android:id="@+id/custom_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Custom View that will be shown full screen

```
public class CustomView extends FrameLayout {
    public interface CloseButtonClickListener {
        void onCloseButtonClicked(int position);
    }

    private TextView positionView;
    private TextView titleView;
    private View closeView;
    private CloseButtonClickListener closeButtonClickListener;
    private int position;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.custom_view, this);
        positionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_view_position);
        titleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_view_title);
        closeView = findViewById(R.id.custom_view_close_button);

        closeView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(closeButtonClickListener != null) {
                    closeButtonClickListener.onCloseButtonClicked(position);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void setData(int position, String title, CloseButtonClickListener closeButtonClickListener) {
        this.position = position;
        this.positionView.setText("" + position);
        this.titleView.setText(title);
        this.closeButtonClickListener = closeButtonClickListener;
    }
}
```

Layout for the custom view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/custom_view_close_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:text="Position:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/custom_view_position"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:paddingBottom="100dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:text="Title:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/custom_view_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

RecyclerView Adapter

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClicked(View v, int position, String title);
    }

    private Context context;
    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
    private List<String> dataList;

    public Adapter(Context context, ItemClickListener itemClickListener, List<String> dataList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
        this.dataList = dataList;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_item, null, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(view, new OnRecyclerItemClickListener());
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ((MyViewHolder) holder).onRecyclerItemClickListener.updatePosition(position);
        ((MyViewHolder) holder).position.setText("" + position);
        ((MyViewHolder) holder).title.setText(dataList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    private class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private OnRecyclerItemClickListener onRecyclerItemClickListener;
        private TextView position;
        private TextView title;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView, OnRecyclerItemClickListener onRecyclerItemClickListener) {
            super(itemView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(onRecyclerItemClickListener);
            this.onRecyclerItemClickListener = onRecyclerItemClickListener;
            this.position = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.position);
            this.title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        }
    }


    private class OnRecyclerItemClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        private int position = -1;

        public void updatePosition(int position) {
            this.position = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(itemClickListener != null) {
                itemClickListener.onItemClicked(v.findViewById(R.id.position), position, dataList.get(position));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Recycler view item layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/position"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/position"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: (Will award the bounty when SO allows me to do it). I think there's no way to do it with an activity, which it's what I thought it was populating. So this is finally the trick!! thank you very mcuh